# Move two Qt tabs to the right, leave rest to the left

Tags: c++, css, qt

I'm trying to figure out how to move two tabs from the QtTabWidget to the right, while leaving the rest to the left.

The tabs are static, aren't added in at run-time.

Here is what I have:
[image: Here is what I have so far]

Here is what I want to have: 
[image: Here is what I want to have]

I've tried editing the stylesheet and adding in `alignment:right;` but that just makes all of them go right, and doesn't work with specific tabs. I also tried things such as `float` and `position:absolute;right:0;` but no luck.

I also couldn't find anything in the [qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html) that seemed like it'd help me here.

So my question is: *How can I move the "Profile" tab, and the "Settings" tab to the right, while leaving the rest where they are?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I think you can't do it with only one `QTabWidget`. First of all, are you sure that you need to use `QTabWidget` but not a `QTabBar`?

Anyway, you can find answer in `QSpacerItem` and **two** `QTabBars`.

1. Create two `QTabBars` with your tabs;
2. Create `QHBoxLayout`;
3. Add first bar to this layout, then add `QSpacerItem` with expanding policy and then add last bar;
4. When you'll click at any bar - you can just show/hide your widgets at the screen by signal/slot.

The problem is - default selected first bar on each `QTabBar`. It's solving by adding empty tab on each `QTabBar`.

Some example code:

```
_firstBar = new QTabBar(this);
_firstBar->addTab("");
_firstBar->addTab("First tab");
_firstBar->addTab("Second tab");
_firstBar->addTab("Third tab");
_firstBar->addTab("Fourth tab");
_firstBar->setDrawBase(false);
_firstBar->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:first { max-width: 0px; border: 0px }");

_secondBar = new QTabBar(this);
_secondBar->addTab("");
_secondBar->addTab("Fifth bar");
_secondBar->addTab("Sixth bar");
_secondBar->setDrawBase(false);
_secondBar->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:first { max-width: 0px; border: 0px }");

QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget);
lay->addWidget(_firstBar);
lay->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed));
lay->addWidget(_secondBar);

connect(_firstBar, &QTabBar::currentChanged, this, &MainWindow::showFirstBarWidget);
connect(_secondBar, &QTabBar::currentChanged, this, &MainWindow::showSecondBarWidget);

_firstBar->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

Here the slots:

```
void MainWindow::showFirstBarWidget(int index)
{
    if(index == 0)
        return;

    _secondBar->setCurrentIndex(0);

    switch(index) {
        // Here code show/hide your QWidget by index
    }
}

void MainWindow::showSecondBarWidget(int index)
{
    if(index == 0)
        return;

    _firstBar->setCurrentIndex(0);

    switch(index) {
        // Here code show/hide your QWidget by index
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 : using a QSpacerItem has always been a good solution for me when putting two things at the opposite sides of a widget